# C# WinForms or WPF App Checkbox List to Install Drivers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I'm very new to C# and .NET and am looking to improve my departments efficiency with installing multiple common programs for our customers.

For now I used a program called Silent Install Builder to add each exe we install and created a checkbox list they can choose which one to install. It fires off the exe that is packaged into the master exe.

I'm looking at creating this in house now either using WPF or WinForms. Looking for a little push into the right direction on what would be the best route for this for a newbie programmer.

[image: Current UI]

Comment: WPF is more latest framework than WinForms. They are sharing same code base called .NET Standard and launching process is included in that. Therefore, there is only difference about UI.

Comment: WinForms is by far much simpler to use than WPF. WPF is state of the art when it comes to UI design, but that can also make it tough to learn. WinForms is great for beginners as it's very straight-forward, it has been around for ages and was quite popular so a lot of questions already have answers.